# How to prevent models added to a collection in BackboneJS from fetching their data once added to collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, view, collections, model

When I initiate my UserList (collection), I fetch all of my Users (models) from my API.

What happens next is what I want to prevent.

It seems that the collection then initializes each model, which triggers the model's .fetch(), for each model.

Why this happens, I don't know. All I am doing is calling .fetch() from my collection.

Code below:

```
var UserList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel,
    url: 'api/user',

    initialize: function() {
        this.fetch();
    }
});

var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'api/user',

    defaults: {
        username: '',
        first_name: '',
        last_name: ''
    },

    initialize: function() {
        if(this.id) {
            this.fetch();
        }
    }
});
```

How do I prevent the newly added models from .fetch() a second time? I already got all the data I needed from the first .fetch() that the collection did when it was initialized.

I still want the UserModel to use .fetch() on .initialize() by default, for when I am trying to view a single User in the web app. I just don't want it to do it when I am trying to view a list of Users.

Comment: if you just want to fetch usermodels only one then don't fetch it again in models initialize

Comment: When I initialize a UserView, I want the model connected to that (UserModel) to .fetch() the data from the API.

But when I am initializing the UserListView), and pass a fresh UserList  (which is a collection) to it, I fetch all model data that is to be added to the collection in one GET request to the API. But then the collection apparently runs .initialize() on each model that it creates and adds to itself, which triggers another .fetch() on each model, which is something I don't want. If the list contains 10 models, that means the app does 11 API calls. Which is something I do not want.

Comment: you have the data already present in the collection , so you dont need to fetch it again take the model from the collection and assign it to view

Comment: I removed the .fetch() within the model's .initialize(), and instead added a .fetch() after I've initialized a UserView that is passed an id. 

 --- that.view = new UserView({ model: new UserModel({ id: id }) });
 --- that.view.model.fetch(); --- Looks quite ugly. Must be some other way around this issue.

Comment: It's still not clear why you'd need to fetch again if you've already fetched it for your collection.

Comment: Well, there might be cases where the actual user tries to navigate to #/user/1 without the collection being initialized. I then need to fetch it from the API.

Answer (score 0):

A trick would be to test if the `Model.initialize` function get attributes or not as arguments like this:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
    initialize: function(attributes) {
        if(Object.keys(attributes).length < 2) {
            this.fetch();
        }
    }
    ...
```

because when the collection wants to populate the models with the data it fetched, it call the model constructor with the data that must be set in this model, and these data are propagated as arguments for the `initialize` function

Comment: In this specific use case your trick would work. But it's just as much of a 'hack' as my 'solution' in the comments above.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a sort of 'hack' because what you are trying to do is the wrong way. The right way is what you called the ugly way :) But that's the right answer to the wrong way question ;)

Answer (score 0):

One option, if you only want the model to fetch when the collection hasn't already been fetched, then check the collection length before fetching in the model's initialize:

```
if (this.collection.length === 0) {
    this.fetch();
}
```

If you've already fetched your collection then presumably the collection length would be 0.